An English single mom goes on a date, neglecting her kids
An English movie, probably sometime around in the 2000s about a single mom with several kids. I remember she goes on a date with a a guy, leaving her kids in the back of the bar. The kids eat from the garbage. Also remember that inspite of being short on cash, she spends the movie on beer for the guy. 
There was also a scene where she fights with a neighbor. 
The movie had very strong English accent and English suburban surroundings. Please help me with the name 

Welcome. I hope you like it here. This good question can be helped with more plot details. Do you recall any more? Do you recall the names of the characters? Was this a suburb of an actual English city? These would help I think.

I was watching the movie Fish Tank today. It triggered my memories about the movie. Fish Tank has very similar surroundings, the not so rich England. I don't remember the name of the characters. The single mom looked miserable and dressed very punk like.

I found the movie. It's actually a short by the same director, Andrea Arnold. It is Wasp (2003). Thanks John

Your are welcome. Feel free to stick around and participate more.

@KopMaverick: you can answer your own question, and accept your own answer. It is encouraged.

The answer was 2003 Andrea Arnold's short Wasp. 
 https://g.co/kgs/Nnq7ou 

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
